# OpenPulse: Where to get current pulse definitions for standard gates?

Tags: qiskit, qasm, openpulse

Is backend.defaults().cmd_def and backend.defaults().pulse_library kept updated regularly? Is this the correct place to pull the best calibrated pulses for the standard gates? I am working on a project now and find I get substantially different results running on OpenQASM vs. OpenPulse as well as running the same pulse schedule a week apart. Thanks!